# "unable to get local issuer certificate" during vagrant up, even after vagrant box add --insecure

Tags: bash, vagrant

The version of Vagrant I installed was 2.2.3 and I am running version 6.3 of Windows 8. 
Let me copy below what I wrote into git bash and what the result was.

```
yishai and shira (master) vagrant $ vagrant box add --insecure bento/ubuntu-16.04 --insecure --force
==> box: Loading metadata for box 'bento/ubuntu-16.04'
    ...
==> box: Successfully added box 'bento/ubuntu-16.04' (v201812.27.0) for 'virtualbox'!
yishai and shira (master) vagrant $ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Box 'bento/ubuntu-16.04' could not be found. Attempting to find and install...
    default: Box Provider: virtualbox
    default: Box Version: = 2.3.5
The box 'bento/ubuntu-16.04' could not be found or
could not be accessed in the remote catalog. If this is a private
box on HashiCorp's Vagrant Cloud, please verify you're logged in via
`vagrant login`. Also, please double-check the name. The expanded
URL and error message are shown below:

URL: ["https://vagrantcloud.com/bento/ubuntu-16.04"]
Error: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
```

Comment: `Error: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate` this is your problem. Something with certificates. The [bento/ubuntu](https://app.vagrantup.com/bento/boxes/ubuntu-16.04) image exists. Does `curl https://vagrantcloud.com/bento/ubuntu-16.04` work?

Comment: Thank you for your response! Apparently curl didn't solve it for me. I received the following output...
...curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.

Comment: yes, and we need to find out why it is _unable to get issuer certificate_. This usually is something with the installation. Try installing/reinstalling/installing different version/installing ca-certificates (or similar packets) and so on.

Comment: The question wasn't whether curl would *solve* the problem, the question is whether curl would *reproduce* the problem, ie. if the faulty certificate store is the same one used by curl, or if the vagrant tooling is using its own store (maybe installed/maintained by something like MacPorts; you haven't told us enough about your platform to make good presumptions).

Comment: BTW, using `--insecure` is a very bad idea -- it is, as the name states, *insecure*; it tells your system to ignore cases where it can't tell between the real web server you actually want to connect to and a fake one handing you a malicious version of your VM that sends spam / acts as a proxy into your network / whatever.

Comment: If this is a corporate environment, you have IT staff. If your system's CA store is out-of-date, that's the kind of problem your IT staff can and will be able to help with. Get it fixed; don't use workarounds that reduce your, and your company's, security.

Comment: Thank you for the tips! Do I have to do something now to reinstitute the security? I am at home, so I don't have IT staff.

Answer (score 17):

You have 2 solutions to fix this issue:

1. You can download the box using `insecure` flag

   ```
   vagrant box add --insecure bento/ubuntu-16.04 --insecure
   ```
2. You can add the `box_download_insecure` flag directly in your Vagrantfile

   ```
   Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
     config.vm.box = "bento/ubuntu-16.04"
     config.vm.box_download_insecure = true
   end
   ```

Comment: Thank you for your response! Unfortunately I got another error.
yishai and shira vagrant $ vagrant box add --insecure bento/ubuntu-16.04 --insecure

Vagrant failed to initialize at a very early stage:

There is a syntax error in the following Vagrantfile. The syntax error
message is reproduced below for convenience:

C:/Users/yishai and shira/FSND-Virtual-Machine/vagrant/Vagrantfile:56: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting end-of-input
*

Comment: yishai and shira vagrant $ vagrant up
Vagrant failed to initialize at a very early stage:

There is a syntax error in the following Vagrantfile. The syntax error
message is reproduced below for convenience:

C:/Users/yishai and shira/FSND-Virtual-Machine/vagrant/Vagrantfile:56: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting end-of-input

Comment: hey, error message is clear, you have something wrong in your `Vagrantfile` line:56

Comment: line 56 just says end

Comment: without full Vagrantfile, its hard to say - there's an error in your file. If you provide the content of the full file, maybe we can spot the error

Comment: can i email it to you?

Comment: no you should edit your question and copy there for everyone to see, maybe someone else will answer

Comment: Passing `--insecure` is, well, *insecure*. This is a much worse "solution" than updating the local certificate store to actually contain the appropriate CA.